# Использует ли класс Thread несколько ядер?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я только начал изучать многопоточное программирование. Узнал, что если у процессора одно ядро, то потоки не выполняются одновременно, а лишь периодически переключатся между друг другом. В свою очередь многоядерные процессоры предоставляют действительное одновременное выполнение двух разных потоков.

**Вопрос:** Использует ли класс `Thread()` несколько ядер или для этого нужно сделать, что-либо ещё ?

Comment: в очень старых версиях java были green thread - вот там могло быть что угодно.

Comment: Нет, но это точно не многопоточность

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вручную *точно* делать ничего не нужно.

Класс Thread просто служит "интеллектуальной связкой" между Вашим кодом и системным планировщиком процессов. Фактически, какой тред выполняется на каком ядре - решает система.

И делает она это виртуозно - ведь задачи такого рода решаются уже десятки лет, и там всё выверено до миллиметров.

Есть *очень редкие исключения*, когда программа сама управляет мэппингом тредов на ядра и вообще тредами. Например, известно, что первые вресии `Oracle` для `Windows NT` "немножко улучшали" системный стек именно в части работы с процессами и потоками.

Но в остальном - Вам нужно просто использовать класс Thread и положиться на *стабильность мироздания*.

Comment: ответ именно относительно java, верно?

Comment: если что, то первые версии java были не от оракла. Хотя кто об этом теперь знает:)

Comment: немного запутался. получается применение обычного класса `Thread` может вызывать использование нескольких ядер (т.н. _параллелизм_). Но весь интернет пишет, что для организации _параллелизма_ нужно использовать некий пакет `java.util.concurrent`. Брешут получается или как это работает?)

Comment: Параллелизм-параллельное исполнение нескольких участков кода. При использовании класса Thread-в рамках одного процесса. А вот когда эти участки кода начинают наперегонки работать с одним набором данных -например, со словарем - тут то и нужен java.util.concurrent